# Axios POST request to Mongodb not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, post, axios

I have a Sign Up modal in my React Bootstrap App to allow registration for new users. I set an onChange event for each attributes to be stored in the database and user should be saved to database if the button Sign Up is clicked, triggering the onClick button. The problem is, the user won't be saved to Mongodb at all. I'm certain the problem is within the SignUpModal code since I did try passing it via node.js on index.js and it worked. The codes are below:

**SignUpModal.js (client side)**

```
  const [userEmail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [userFullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [userType, setType] = useState("");

//add user to database
  const addUser = () => {
    Axios.post("/addUser", {
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword,
      userFullName: userFullName,
      userType: userType,
    });
  };

    return(
        <Modal
          {...props}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              Sign Up Form
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Form>
          <Modal.Body>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="userEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here"  
                        onChange = {(event) => {
                          setEmail(event.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="userPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" 
                    onChange = {(event) => {
                      setPassword(event.target.value);
                    }}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="userFullName">
                    <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter full name here" 
                    onChange = {(event) => {
                      setFullName(event.target.value);
                    }}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formType">
                    <Form.Label>I am a... (Tick one of the options below):</Form.Label>
                    {['radio'].map((type) => (
                        <div key={`inline-${type}`} className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Client"
                            name="group1"
                            type={type}
                            id={`inline-${type}-1`}
                            onChange = {(event) => {
                              setType(event.target.value);
                            }}
                        />
                        <Form.Check
                            inline
                            label="Service provider"
                            name="group1"
                            type={type}
                            id={`inline-${type}-2`}
                            onChange = {(event) => {
                              setType(event.target.value);
                            }}
                        />
                        </div>
                        ))}
                </Form.Group>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick= {addUser}>
                    Sign Up!
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
          </Form>
        </Modal>
)
}
```

**index.js (server side)**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserModel = require("./models/User");

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://tryweb:password1234@cluster5.c58gv.mongodb.net/user?retryWrites=true&w=majority", 
    {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
});

app.post("/addUser", async(req, res) => {

    const user = new UserModel(
        {   userEmail: req.body.userEmail, 
            userPassword: req.body.userPassword, 
            userFullName: req.body.userFullName, 
            userType: req.body.userType
        }
    );

    try{
        await user.save();
    }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running in port 3000...");
});
```

I have tried changing the URL to `http://localhost:3000/addUser` and it still does not work. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: in app.js what is the route name u assigned for index.js page? `app.use("/auth", userRoutes);` something like this? It should be `http://localhost:3000/auth/addUser`

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake I haven't set any route yet since I am only trying to save to database first. Or is it necessary?

Comment: Is there an error message that you're getting?

Comment: can u please share ur app.js code? I am somewhat new to coding myself. But so far I always used the app.js maybe there are other ways

Comment: @DogEatDog None from the console when I debugged it, but the URL did change to something weird: ```http://localhost:3000/?group1=on```

Comment: Sounds like the form and Axios are erroring somewhere. Do console.log in `const addUser = () => {` ... it might be erroring prior to getting to the server.

Comment: @DogEatDog yes, I tried doing that with email, password and full name, and the console shows the output just fine. Nothing is saved to database tho

Answer (score 0):

This looks good, but you might be hitting an error with the data or within the browser. Try logging the data as it comes into the request with `console.log(req.body)`.

Try this:

Assuming that your `./models/User` looks something like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let User = new Schema(
  {
    userEmail: {
      type: String
    },
    userPassword: {
      type: String
    },
    userFullName: {
      type: String
    },
    userType: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  { collection: "Users" }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

And the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserModel = require("./models/User");

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const mongooseConnectionString = "mongodb+srv://tryweb:password1234@cluster5.c58gv.mongodb.net/user?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const mongooseConnection = mongoose.connect(mongooseConnectionString, 
    {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
});

// Let us know we established connection
mongooseConnection.once("open", function() {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

app.post("/addUser", async(req, res) => {

    const user = new UserModel(req.body);

    try{
        await user.save();
        response.send(user);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running in port 3000...");
});
```